# how do i factory reset my tablet that has no physical volume buttons

Tags: factory-reset

i have a TG-TEK tablet and i cant remeber my password and don't know how to factory reset my tablet because it has no physical volume buttons

Comment: Does the tablet have menu buttons at least?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

- Press the power button to get the option menu and dislay:

  > Power off
  >
  > Reboot
- On that menu, hold down that power off option on your touch screen while also holding down the home button on the side of your tablet.
- This should bring up a screen to reboot into safe mode.
- Hit yes for safe mode and then hold down your power and home buttons till the logo appears.
- Release both buttons and hit the power button one time and then hold only the home button down till a menu option appears.
- Use the home button to move down to factory reset and press the power button to select. Once it says complete then use the power button to select reboot.

This works on tablets without physical buttons, but have menu button. Should work on yours too.

If the above doesn't work, there still the computer solutions where one can just flash the firmware.